# CasperJS screenshot comes as blank after selecting a link

Tags: dojo, casperjs

Using casperJS script, after successful login into application, and clicking on a link, following error is thrown and web page comes as blank:

```
  ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating  
  'g.getItem.bind(g)')  
  TRACE:  
  -> scripts/dojo/dojo/dojo.js: 20  
  ERROR: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating  
  'g.getItem.bind(g)')
```

The application is build on top of dojo.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve written some code that tries to use `Function.prototype.bind`. `Function.prototype.bind` doesn’t exist in PhantomJS. You need to change your code to use `dojo/_base/lang.hitch` instead.